# Error: A non-empty array is required for 'in' filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create custom hook that will run react-firebase-hooks library hook: **useCollection**. I use redux toolkit in my project as a state manager, and redux provides my custom hook with the game data. I need to grab connected players IDs from store: `game.players: string[]`. But the thing is that sometimes game won't be fetched still, sometimes it cab be `null` and new created game does not have any connected players.

I've created my own implementation:

```
export const useGamePlayers = () => {
    const {game} = useTypedSelector(state => state.game);

    return useCollection(
        query(collection(db, 'players'), where(documentId(), 'in', game?.players))
    )
};
```

But when i use this hook I see this error: *Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid Query. A non-empty array is required for 'in' filters.* This is happening beacause new game has 0 connected players.

So the question is - **How can I conditionally execute hook depending on the array length?**

Comment: What's your question? It sounds like you are aware of the problem that the error message is communicating. You can't have an empty array there, so you will have to decide what should happen differently in that case.

Comment: @DougStevenson My problem is that I cannot use react hooks conditionally. I need to stop hook execution if the data (connected players array) is invalid. So the question is: How can I conditionally execute hook depending on array length?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your comment. It made me rethink the problem, so I found out that i can pass `null` instead of `query(collection...)` when players array is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. The thing i didn't get is that I can pass null instead of querying collection when no players are connected or players array doesn't exists.

```
export const useGamePlayers = () => {
    const {game} = useTypedSelector(state => state.game);

    return useCollection(
        game?.players.length
            ? query(collection(db, 'players'), where(documentId(), 'in', game.players)) 
            : null
    )
};
```